# ¿Cómo establecer correctamente etiqueta Authorize en controlador?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo la siguiente etiqueta en mi controlador (.Net Framework 4), algo como esto:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administradores, LiberadorComercial, LiberadorComercialAL, LiberadorComercialAZBolsas, LiberadorComercialAZFraccionada, LiberadorCreditos, LiberadorConsignatarios, LiberadorLogistica, LiberadorFinanzas, Apb700, Apb712, Apb714, Apb719, Apb728, Apb730, Apb748")]

 public class LiberacionController : Controller
```

y nesecito obtener la cadena de los Roles desde DB.
¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?
Intente con esto, pero no esta funcionando

Mi código:

```
[Authorize(Roles = nameof(GetDynamicRolesMax))]
    public class LiberacionController : Controller
    

public IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicRolesMax()
        {
            try {
                var holds = this._holdTypeService.GetHoldType();
                var roles = this._holdTypeService.GetStrApbsMax(holds);

                IEnumerable<string> lista = roles.Split(',');
                return lista;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            
        }
```